# How to use generic types with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a generic type with dynamic function when nothing is passed, but if a type is passed, I want to use the defined type instead. Example:

1. Here I'm declaring all my generic parameters;

   ```
   type SocketType = {
      coolType: string,
      foo: number,
      bar: number[]
   }
   ```
2. Here I'm declaring another type, completely different from SocketType;

   ```
   type AnotherSocketType = {
      ipsum: () => void,
      blabla: string,
      towMater: number
   }
   ```
3. My generic function dictionary type:

   ```
   type SocketFunctions = {
       [key: string]: <T = SocketType>(data: T) => void
   }
   ```
4. Both dictionaries (firstFunctionsList and secondFunctionsList) can add or remove methods to use when necessary:

   ```
   // This step represent my compile error
   const firstFunctionsList: SocketFunctions = {
      function_one: (value) => {
         // when I hover the value, VSCode shows: (parameter) value: T = SocketType
         const data = value.coolType;  // <- here, the compile show error: property 'coolType' does not exist in 'T'.
         {...}
      }
   }

   const secondFunctionsList: SocketFunctions = {}
   ```
5. I will check if method exists, an if method is valid, I want to pass some value as SocketType or AnotherSocketType:

   ```
   const firstData: SocketType = {
      coolType: "this is a cool string",
      foo: 8273,
      bar: [1, 2, 3, 4]
   }

   const secondData: AnotherSocketType = {
      ipsum: () => { //do something },
      blabla: "The lazy fox jumps over bla bla bla",
      towMater: 1522
   }

   const test = 'someFunctionName';

   const firstFunc = firstFunctionsList[test];
   const secondFunc = secondFunctionsList[test];

   if(typeof firstFunc === 'function') firstFunc(firstData);                         // Here, I want that function received value as SocketType
   if(typeof secondFunc === 'function') secondFunc<AnotherSocketType>(secondData);   // Here, I want that function received value as AnotherSocketType
   ```

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what the question is. You are stating some facts, but never actually ask a question. What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: My problem its visible in 4th item

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to parameterize the `SocketFunctions` type with your generic type. For instance, this works for me:

```
type SocketType = {
  coolType: string,
  foo: number,
  bar: number[]
}

type AnotherSocketType = {
  ipsum: () => void,
  blabla: string,
  towMater: number
}

type SocketFunctions<T = SocketType> = {
  [key: string]: (data: T) => void
}

const firstFunctionsList: SocketFunctions = {
  function_one: (value) => {
     const data = value.coolType;
  }
}

const secondFunctionsList: SocketFunctions<AnotherSocketType> = {
  function_one: (value) => {
    const data = value.blabla;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can keep your original formulation, but you have to bind the type to `function_one` differently. In this arrangement, though, you don't know what type `data` is within the declaration of `function_one`. I'm guessing the implementation you want is my first suggestion, but this version may also work for your purposes.

```
const firstFunctionsList: SocketFunctions = {
  function_one: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
};

firstFunctionsList.function_one({ coolType: "hello", foo: 1, bar: [1, 2, 3] });
firstFunctionsList.function_one<AnotherSocketType>({
  ipsum: () => {},
  blabla: "hello",
  towMater: 1,
});
```

Comment: These solution don't work for me, because each function in `functionList` can receive a specific type, for example:
`firstFunctionsList.function_one()` can receive AnotherSocketType, but in the same object there can be `function_two`, which will receive a parameter of another type, like `SocketType `, for example.
Im using this structure for avoid if/else in code, and allow the code to be easily scalable..

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using Generics try and apply it to your use case.

```
function addArray<T>(arr: T[]): T[]{
    return new Array().concat(arr)
}

let array = addArray<number>([1,2,3,4])
console.log(array)
```